# React When does rendering happen

Tags: reactjs, redux, render, redux-saga, dvajs

My project use `dvajs`(Based on redux and redux-saga), The code below is to send a request after clicking the button, change the status through connect, and then call the ant design component `message.error` an `message.success`(Similar to alert) to remind

```
import type { Dispatch } from 'umi';
import ProForm, { ProFormText } from '@ant-design/pro-form';
import { message } from 'antd';

const tip = (type: string, content: string) => {
  if (type === 'error') message.error(content, 5);
  else message.success(content, 5);
};

const RegisterFC: React.FC<RegisterProps> = (props) => {
  const { registerResponseInfo = {}, submitting, dispatch } = props;
  const { status } = registerResponseInfo;

  const handleSubmit = (values: RegisterParamsType) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'register/register',
      payload: { ...values },
   });
};      

  return (
    <div>
      <ProForm
         onFinish={(values) => {
            handleSubmit(values as RegisterParamsType);
            return Promise.resolve();
    }}
       >
       <ProFormText/>
       ...
      {
        status === '1' && !submitting && (
          tip('error',
            intl.formatMessage({
              id: 'pages.register.status1.message',
              defaultMessage: 'error'
            })
          )
        )
      }
    <<ProForm>/>
    </div>
  )
}

const p = ({ register, loading }: { register: RegisterResponseInfo, loading: Loading; }) => {
  console.log(loading);
  return {
    registerResponseInfo: register,
    submitting: loading.effects['register/register'],
  };
};

export default connect(p)(RegisterFC);
```

When I click the button, the console prompts：

> Warning: Render methods should be a pure function of props and state;
> triggering nested component updates from render is not allowed. If
> necessary, trigger nested updates in componentDidUpdate.

Doesn't the component re-render when the state changes? Does the tip function change the state?

Comment: The code that's here is incomplete and confusing.  What is `p` and where is it called?  How does `handleSubmit` access `dispatch`? (is it inside of a component?)  I am getting a different error which is due to you printing the `void` results from `tip()` inside your `div`.  `tip` updates the global `message` object but it does not return anything.

Comment: Sorry, I only intercepted part of the code due to too much code. I have made further improvements to the code. `p` is called by `connect` in the last line, `handleSubmit` should be inside the component. You mean to add `return` in `tip()`?

Comment: It's fine for `tip` to be `void` but you should be calling it outside of the component's `return` JSX.  Somewhere in the body of the component, `if (status === '1' && !submitting) { tip(...); }`

Comment: Ok, but if I replace `tip(..)` with `FunctionComponent`, the warning will not appear. Why? code show as below `{ status === '0' && !submitting && (  <RegisterMessage />} `

Comment: `<RegisterMessage />` is a JSX element that you are rendering to the DOM.  The result of calling `tip()` is nothing.  It is `void`.  So you cannot render it.

Comment: I modify `tip() return jsx.element` and the warning disappeared. This way of writing is like conditional rendering. If the `tip()` is void, react will think that I am changing the state.You solved my doubts, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution: Call `tip` Outside of `return`

`tip` is just a `function` that you are calling.  You should call it outside of the `return` JSX section of your code.  I think it makes the most sense to call it inside of a `useEffect` hook with dependencies on `status` and `submitting`. The effect runs each time that `status` or `submitting` changes.  If `status` is `1` and `submitting` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), then we call `tip`.

```
const RegisterFC: React.FC<RegisterProps> = (props) => {
    const { registerResponseInfo = {}, submitting, dispatch } = props;
    const { status } = registerResponseInfo;

    const handleSubmit = (values: RegisterParamsType) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'register/register',
            payload: { ...values },
        });
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (status === '1' && !submitting) {
            tip('error',
                intl.formatMessage({
                    id: 'pages.register.status1.message',
                    defaultMessage: 'error'
                })
            );
        }
    }, [status, submitting]);

    return (
        <div>...</div>
    )
}
```

#### Explanation

> Render methods should be a pure function of props and state

The render section of a component (`render()` in class component or `return` in a function component) is where you create the JSX (React HTML) markup for your component based on the current values of `props` and `state`.  It should not have any side effects.  It creates and returns JSX and that's it.

Calling `tip` is a side effect since it modifies the global `antd` `messsage` object.  That means it shouldn't be in the `render` section of the code.  Side effects are generally handled inside of `useEffect` hooks.

You are trying to conditionally render `tip` like you would conditionally render a component.  The problem is that `tip` is **not a component**.  A function component is a function which returns a JSX Element.  `tip` is a `void` function that returns nothing, so you cannot render it.